# JavaScript: Why am I getting "undefined" when trying to assign value from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I see this question has been asked many, many times.
I apologize for posting another question about the same.

I am reading values from an excel file
Sometimes the excel file headers are: LegistarID AgendaItem, Title
Other times the excel headers are: File #, Agenda #, Title

```
LegistarID = File #
AgendaItem = Agenda #
```

I attempt to get the value assigned to a scope variable  $scope.IsAgenda whether is coming from, AgendaItem, or Agenda # from the excel file.

I attempt to get the value assigned to a scope variable  $scope.IsLegistar whether is coming from, LegistarID, or File # from the excel file.

When the code passes the assignment line using Agenda #:

```
$scope.IsAgenda = !row.hasOwnProperty("AgendaItem") ? String(row["Agenda #"]) : String(row["AgendaItem"]);
```

I end up with an "undefined" value for $scope.IsAgena, even though I can see there is a value.

Same exact for LegistarID.

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Am I doing the syntax wrong? How do I have to read the value from the object?

Please any help is appreciated.

Thank you,
Erasmo

Comment: The code you shared looks right. If `$scope.isAgenda` gets its value here, which it should, then it probably is losing the value somewhere else. Where exactly in your code do you see it as `undefined`? Did you try logging its value right after line `366`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try:

```
$scope.IsAgenda = row["AgendaItem"] == undefined ? String(row["Agenda #"]) : String(row["AgendaItem"]);
```

Comment: I tried both suggestions, and I still get the same result. I see that when I mouse over 'row' I see that there is a key/value for Agenda #, but when I add a watch to row["Agenda #"], then I get the undefined property. Similar to what you see in the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `hasOwnProperty`, just check for the actual value. The first condition checks for all [falsy values of javascript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/falsy-values-in-javascript/) the second one is two ensure that `0` evaluates to true, assuming zero should should be true!

```
$scope.IsAgenda = !(row['AgendaItem'] || row['AgendaItem'] === 0) ? String(row["Agenda #"]) : String(row["AgendaItem"]);
```

Comment: Let me give that a try. Thank you.